# What does Brendan say to Paddy Conlon in the movie "Warrior"

Tags: plot-explanation, warrior

In a scene in [*Warrior*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1291584/), Paddy Conlon visits Brendan's house during night, trying to convince Brendan to allow him to visit Brendan's family.

Brendan says something like: "I know why you are here, you are here to ***glow (glue)***?" Paddy replies "I am not here to ***glow (glue)***".

I did not get the last word of their conversation, I can get it contextually (I can be wrong).

> Background: Paddy Conlon has been an abusive and alcoholic father to Brendan; Brendan refuses to allow Paddy to come close to Brendan's family. Paddy has been sober for a while and tries to make it up to his son. Brendan thinks Paddy comes over to make a scene or to beg for money.

Comment: The word they're using is "gloat".

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, thanks. I did not get it. Much appreciated.